# Image display through codeigniter using header

Tags: php, image, codeigniter, header

```
public function set_gcm_image_resolution()
 {
    $link='images/gcm_images';
    $image_url= base_url()."$link/banner_bg.jpg";


    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($image_url);

  $calculation=$width/3;

 $image_size='ldpi';
    switch($image_size)
    {       
        case "ldpi":    
        $cd =& get_instance();
    $cfg['image_library'] = 'gd2';
    $cfg['source_image']= $image_url;
    $cfg['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
    $config['new_image']=
    $cfg['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
    $cfg['width']    = round($calculation*0.75,'0');
    $cd->image_lib->clear();
    $cd->image_lib->initialize($cfg); 
    $result=$cd->image_lib->resize();

    return $result;

    break;

    }
}
```

Am trying to call this function to display a image,but its not working,i tried everything,but no use, can some one tell me how to display image using (header content type...etc),when this function calls

Comment: which part is not working??

Comment: i want to display image,so how to display it

Answer (score 1):

Your code should be like this as per your requirement :

```
function set_gcm_image_resolution()
{
    $link = 'images/gcm_images';
    $image_url = base_url() . "$link/banner_bg.jpg";


    list($width, $height) = getimagesize($image_url);

    $calculation = $width / 3;

    $image_size = 'ldpi';
    switch ($image_size) {
        case "ldpi":
            $cd = & get_instance();
            $cfg['image_library'] = 'gd2';
            $cfg['source_image'] = $image_url;
            $cfg['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
            $config['new_image'] = $cfg['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
            $cfg['width'] = round($calculation * 0.75, '0');
            $cd->image_lib->clear();
            $cd->image_lib->initialize($cfg);
            $result = $cd->image_lib->resize();
            $this->setHeader($image_url);
            echo readfile($image_url);
            //echo $result;

            break;
    }

    exit;
}

function setHeader($imagepath)
{
    $imgInfo = getimagesize($imagepath);
    if ($imgInfo[2] == 1) {
        $cd->output->set_header('Content-Type: image/gif');
    } else if ($imgInfo[2] == 2) {
        $cd->output->set_header('Content-Type: image/jpg');
    } else if ($imgInfo[2] == 3) {
        $cd->output->set_header('Content-Type: image/png');
    }

    $cd->output->set_header("Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 2020 05:00:00 GMT");
}
```